# update query statement looping multiple times with results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, sql-update

I have used following looping condition in order to update the database. I am getting multiple rows from select statement. And now i want to store those rows in database using update statement.In this condition multiple update statement are getting looped and because of that my database is not getting updated. I just want to loop update query single time and multiple rows from select statement gets stored in the database. Its just small mistake i am doing not able to identify wrong looping i guess.

Here is my code:

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'save-widget-news')
{

        if(($param['news'])==4){

        $sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news.datum_archiv,ad_news_texte.id
            FROM autodo.ad_news_texte
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
            WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv
            BETWEEN curdate( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate( ) ) +28
            DAY AND curdate( )";    
        }
            elseif(($param['news'])==6){

        $sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news.datum_archiv,ad_news_texte.id
            FROM autodo.ad_news_texte
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
            WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv
            BETWEEN curdate( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate( ) ) +42
            DAY AND curdate( )";

            }
            elseif(($param['news'])==10){

        $sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news.datum_archiv,ad_news_texte.id
            FROM autodo.ad_news_texte
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
            INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
            WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv
            BETWEEN curdate( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate( ) ) +70
            DAY AND curdate( )";

            }

            $sql_select=mysql_query($sql);  
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)) {
            echo $update="UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w SET w.configuration='".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($row['headline']))."' WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=2 ";
            $update_news=mysql_query($update, $myConnection);
            }
```

In firebug i checked here is how it is looping and executing the update condition multiple times which i dont want:

```
UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w 
SET w.configuration='s:65:\"AutoDo! News: Neue Pflichtfelder für Neuwagen bei AutoScout24.de!\";' 
WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=2;

UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w 
SET w.configuration='s:65:\"New intercompany prices for delivery to Schmitz Cargobull Russia.\";' 
WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=2;

UPDATE dashboard_widget_users w 
SET w.configuration='s:22:\"AutoDo! startet durch.\";' 
WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=2;
```

Comment: will the select statement result always one record or multiple records in any of the condition? - You have 3 condition i.e. `news` as 4, 6 and 10 - so is it like, only one record/result will come in each condition?

Comment: select statement always result multiple record every time..

Comment: If it will return multiple result, so which one u need to store in DB? the first record or the last record or any specific record? As you are using a static where condition as `WHERE w.dsnr_yw_user =12 AND w.dsnr_dashboard_widget=2`.

Comment: Please check the updated question update statement is executing multiple times with results. And because of that i am not able to store it into the database

Comment: so, which one u need to save in DB? `s:65:\"AutoDo! News:...` OR `s:65:\"New intercompany...` OR `s:22:\"AutoDo!...`

Comment: i want to save all the results coming from select statment in database using update statement...thts why i have used while condition but its looping my update statements itself not the results...

Comment: UPDATE statement means - it will update the record in DB.
For the first time, it will update this value `s:65:\"AutoDo! News:...` in DB where the condition get satisfied, in second loop, the value will be updated to `s:65:\"New intercompany...` and in third loop, `s:22:\"AutoDo!...` will be updated. You can not get 3 of the data in the same field with some specific condition. And if it is totally not updating DB, then please do not write `echo $update`. Write only `$update`.

Comment: i can i think instead of loop if i use update query using select statement then ? there should be some way right ?